# Where can I ask a question about the scientific community's perception of unverifiable results?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where would a question asking about how scientists view results that can't be independently verified (like when there's only one apparatus that has conducted the experiment, e.g. LIGO and CERN) be appropriate? As it would have to do with the community's response, maybe Academia.SE; however, it specifically deals with the scientific method (which limits its target audience). As it doesn't talk about the actual problems themselves, I'm thinking Physics.SE (since I'd figure the above examples would be particularly relevant to physics) would probably be inappropriate.

Comment: Philosophy.SE does handle questions about the Philosophy of Science. If that's too abstract, I do think Academia would be best. Disclaimer: I'm a mere lurker on both sites.

Comment: Ironically your question about what to do with a lack of information sounds like it'd really be lacking enough information to conclusively answer.  I'd expect there to really need a specific example to really say much about what can, and can't, be done, or asserted, in that situation.